# Apple Watch Video Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

Is there any control or way we can play video in `Apple Watch` app. I can see `Image`, `Button`, `Label` etc.. controls but couldn't find a way to play a video.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @user3746428 you should add this as the correct answer

Comment: @user3746428, yes you should add this as an answer so I can accept. There is no way at the moment for video-playback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to playback video on the Apple Watch currently. And I doubt there will be for some time (if ever) due to the very small screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is possible now, I am adding some reference URL so other developers can get an idea and possibility for this.

Watch OS 2 comes up with plenty of nice features and [Audio and Video](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH24-SW1) are part of this.